# How to have multiple items per row to MaterialDrawer?

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I am using the great library [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) to add a navigation drawer to my app. It's working very well so far, but I'm wondering if there's a way to add multiple items per row. For example, to show multiple related settings the can be toggled.

I went through the library documentation and the issue tracker on Github but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create your own custom layout inside the `NavigationView` in the `DrawerLayout`. For example, the following code has a 4 rows with 3 items in each row.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AAFFAA"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:layout_gravity="end">
        <GridLayout
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:rowCount="4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
                android:rowOrderPreserved="true">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="sin"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="cos"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="tan"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="ln"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="log"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="!"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="\u03c0"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="e"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="^"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="("/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text=")"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="\u221a"/>

        </GridLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `MaterialDrawer` [documentation](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) does state that it's possible to use a [Custom DrawerLayout Implementation](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#can-i-use-my-own-drawerlayout-implementation), But I've never done that before, So I'm unable to provide a sample for that at the moment.